# Bad Request while sending SMS from php

Tags: php, curl, sms-gateway

I am using indiasms's api with curl to send sms

```
 <?php        

 $url = "http://12.23.54.18/api/smsapi.aspx?username=myusername&password=mypassword&to=7897015426&from=DEMOAB&message=Your message content.";            
 $curl = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
                ));

 $resp = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);

 ?>
```

Whenever I run this script I get

**Bad Request**

**HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.**

What i am doing wrong. ??

Update But when i run without curl it works fine

```
<a href="http://12.23.54.18/api/smsapi.aspx?username=myusername&password=mypassword&to=7897015426&from=DEMOAB&message=Your message content.">Send Message</a>
```

When i click this link it works normally

Comment: Are you URL encoding the message? What does the API documentation say?

Comment: Cody, your webservice requires POST method?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento no

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ there is nothing about URL encoding here

Comment: I would also guess, that the problem is the encoding of the message. Try to rawurlencode your message.

Comment: @Johni good tip! Please post a answer! +1 for your future answer :)

Comment: Why don't you just remove the: CURLOPT_URL and CURLOPT_USERAGENT lines and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposedly the direct link works, because all headers needed for the request was sent.

I believe the lack of `User-Agent:` header or `Connection:` header

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://12.23.54.18/api/smsapi.aspx?username=myusername&password=mypassword&to=7897015426&from=DEMOAB&message=Your message content.');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

echo $httpcode;
```

If not work, try add, `Connection:` header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Connection: close'
));
```

If not work, try enconde your "message" before send:

```
$msg = rawurlencode('Your message content.');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://12.23.54.18/api/smsapi.aspx?username=myusername&password=mypassword&to=7897015426&from=DEMOAB&message=' . $msg);
```

Comment: @Cody this WebService requires AUTH cookie/session or use only "GET method"? See I edited the answer.

Comment: Used `rawurlencode`? Thanks to the tip @Jonhi :) Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Good luck in your project!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64791/discussion-between-cody-and-guilherme-nascimento).